# How to remove a label from the Neo4j Browser interface?

Tags: neo4j

I created a node accidentally with the wrong label so I deleted it, but now this type-o forever lives as a node label in my browser interface. How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

Right now it's not possible, it just lives in the store until you recreate or copy the store and leave it out (you can use my [store-utils](https://github.com/jexp/store-utils) for that)

In Neo4j 2.3 the label will no longer be displayed.